# Eject excess space from string in C

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I need to write a function which will eject excess space from string in C.

Example:

```
char s[]="  abcde    abcde    ";
```

OUTPUT:

```
"abcde abcde"
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
char *eject(char *str) {
  int i, x;
  for (i = x = 0; str[i]; ++i)
    if (!isspace(str[i]) || (i > 0 && !isspace(str[i - 1])))
      str[x++] = str[i];
  if(x > 0 && str[x-1] == ' ') str[x-1] = '\0';
  return str;
}

int main() {
  char s[] = "  abcde    abcde    ";
  printf("\"%s\"", eject(s));
  return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't work for string `"          "`
If this string is found program should print:

```
""
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide more detail than "this doesn't work"?

Comment: Every time you find an extra space, you need to shift all the following characters in the string to the left.

Comment: Well strings are new to me. I'm beginner and this simple task is hard for me. Could anyone write me program with simple explanation?

Comment: `while(*q<n)` looks suspicious. The `*q` is a character from the string, and `n` is the string length.

Comment: You need two positions — the one you're reading from and the one you're writing to.  At first they're synchronized, but they become unsynchronized once you come across multiple spaces.  Since you're only removing characters, the operation can be done in situ in safety.

Comment: Don't forget to NUL-terminate the shortened string.

Comment: I edited my code, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: *"This code doesn't remove the last space. How to fix this?"* Check the last character when you terminate the string.

Comment: @WeatherVane how to check the last character?

Comment: `if(x > 0 && str[x-1] == ' ') str[x-1] = '\0';`

Comment: thanks, now the problem is that this doesn't work for the empty string

Comment: Check for the empty string.

Comment: I edited question, could someone fix code?

Comment: You will learn more by doing the work yourself.  You've made an effort; that is indisputable.  But pleading for someone to fix your code is unlikely to achieve your goal and will quite likely mean you get downvotes.

Comment: Run your code in a debugger.  It will show you what is happening, and from there, you should be able to fix the problem.

Comment: My testing of the code in [Revision 4](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71026982/4) of the question indicates that it correctly handles empty strings and strings of all blanks — 1 and many blanks.   The was one test case that it didn't handle correctly, namely `"abc  def"` (with two blanks in the middle; that was not null-terminated properly so I got `abc deff` as the output.

Comment: I added a few more test cases and got more erroneous output: `Before: [abc   def]` and 
`After:  [abc defef]` —— `Before: [abc    xyz   def]` and `After:  [abc xyz def  def]`.  One fix for that is simply to add `str[x] = '\0';` before the `return` in the function.  Note that you were already reminded (told) to ensure you null-terminate the string – your code doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to remove the consecutive space characters between the words in the input string and all leading and trailing space characters of the input string. That means, write code to remove the consecutive space characters in the input string and while removing the consecutive space characters, remove the leading and trailing space characters completely.

You can do it in just one iteration. No need to write the different functions for removing the leading and trailing spaces of input string, as shown in the other post.

You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * eject (char *str) {
    if (str == NULL) {
        printf ("Invalid input..\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Pointer to keep track of position where next character to be write 
     */
    char * p = str;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; str[i] ; ++i) {
        if ((isspace (str[i])) && ((p == str) || (str[i + 1] == '\0') || (str[i] == (str[i + 1])))) {
            continue;
        }
        *p++ = str[i];
    }

    /* Add the null terminating character. 
     */
    *p = '\0';
    return str;
}

int main (void) {
  char s[] = "  abcde    abcde    ";
  printf("\"%s\"\n", eject(s));

  char s1[] = "      ";
  printf("\"%s\"\n", eject(s1));

  char s2[] = "ab  yz   ";
  printf("\"%s\"\n", eject(s2));

  char s3[] = "  ddd xx  jj m";
  printf("\"%s\"\n", eject(s3));

  char s4[] = "";
  printf("\"%s\"\n", eject(s4));

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
"abcde abcde"
""
"ab yz"
"ddd xx jj m"
""
```

Comment: so simple, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You could write two functions which trim leading and trailing whitespace characters.

```
void trim_front(char *src) {
    size_t i = 0, j = 0;
    while (isspace(src[i])) i++;
    while (i < strlen(src)) src[j++] = src[i++];
    src[j] = '\0';
}

void trim_back(char *src) {
    char *ch = src + strlen(src) - 1;
    while (isspace(*ch)) *ch-- = '\0';
}
```

If you know you don't have to deal with trailing or leading spaces, your task becomes much simpler.

```
void reduce_spaces(char *src) {
    size_t i = 0, j = 0;

    for (; i < strlen(src); ++i) {
        if (i == strlen(src) - 1 || 
            (isspace(src[i]) && !isspace(src[i + 1])) ||
            !isspace(src[i])) {
            src[j++] = src[i];
        }
    }

    src[j] = '\0';
}
```

And testing this:

```
int main(void) {
    char s[] = "     hello    world     ";

    trim_front(s);
    trim_back(s);
    reduce_spaces(s);

    printf(">%s<\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

```
% gcc test.c
% ./a.out
>hello world<
%
```

Of course, if you really want to, you can transplant the code from those functions into `reduce_spaces`, but decomposing a problem into multiple smaller problems can make things much easier.

Comment: could you put the whole program as answer?

Comment: this returns with one extra space on the end

Comment: Edited to include `main` and example terminal output from running it.

Comment: I get an error: The program accesses a variable that is not initialized for this line:  while (isspace(*ch)) *ch-- = '\0';

Comment: An error, or a warning? Though I'm not sure where either comes from, as `ch` is the only variable in play, and it's definitely initialized.

Comment: I have strong autotest defined in the development environment of my university

Comment: thank you very much, this solved my task

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more advanced answer just for reference - suppose you were tasked in writing a professional library for the use in real world programs. Then one would first list all requirements that make sense:

- It's good practice to treat strings as "immutable" - that is, build up a new string based on the old one rather than in-place replacement.
- Take the destination string as parameter but also return a pointer to it (similar to `strcpy` etc functions).
- In case of empty strings, set the destination string empty too.
- Remove all "white space" not just the `' '` character.
- Instead of always inserting a space character after each word, why not insert a variable delimiter? Might as well be something like `,` or `;`.
- No delimiter should be inserted after the last word.
- The algorithm should only traverse the data once for performance reasons. That is, internal calls like `strlen` etc are unacceptable.
- Byte by byte iteration is fine - we need not care about alignment.

Then we might come up with something like this:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* trim_delimit (char* restrict dst, const char* restrict src, char delim)
{
  char* start = dst;
  *dst = '\0';
  
  bool remove_spaces = true;
  char* insert_delim_pos = NULL;
  
  for(; *src != '\0'; src++)
  {
    if(remove_spaces)
    {
      if(!isspace(*src))
      {
        remove_spaces = false;
        if(insert_delim_pos != NULL)
        {
          // we only get here if more words were found, not yet at the end of the string
          *insert_delim_pos = delim; 
          insert_delim_pos = NULL;
        }
      }
    }

    if(!remove_spaces)
    {
      if(isspace(*src))
      {
        remove_spaces = true;
        insert_delim_pos = dst; // remember where to insert delimiter for later
      }
      else
      {
        *dst = *src;
      }
      dst++;
    }
  }

  return start;
}
```

Test cases:

```
int main (void)
{
  char s[]="  abcde    abcde    "; 
  char trimmed[100];

  puts(trim_delimit(trimmed, s, ' '));
  puts(trim_delimit(trimmed, "", ' '));
  puts(trim_delimit(trimmed, s, ';'));
}
```

Output:

```
abcde abcde

abcde;abcde
```